# Can I marry a girl if I'm also a girl?

Tags: harvest-moon-3d-a-new-beginning

Most of the Harvest Moon Games i've played (GBA+) you've either been a boy or a girl with the 2 on separate games, Harvest Moon A New Beginning has been the first game where I can play as both a boy or a girl, and as such it would be expected within the game the Heart Events and marriage system has been fixed up for both the guys and the girls.

So I am wondering if you can start the game as a girl, and pursue to marry one of the girls?

Comment: There are male marriage candidates for females. Just thought I would make sure you know, since its not obvious from the question

Comment: @Lawton before the edit my question was "Can Harvest Moon A New Begining have Same Sex Relationships" however it was changed since the reason why i was asking the question was because of the last line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot.  Just like every other Harvest Moon game, you can only pursue opposite sex marriages.  You can become friends with them, but there is no mechanic in-game that will allow you to marry them.