# How many children can I adopt?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I am wondering how many children in total I can adopt at any given time. If the number is dependent on where our home is, then which home allows me the most?

Comment: As far as i know, the amount of children you can adopt is limited to 2. But since im not entirely sure, i just post this as  a comment.^^

Comment: are you trying to create funny question titles? You have 3 questions with interesting titles in no time xD

Comment: @SysDragon not really, this one and the vampire are logical based off the body and the same sex one i was going to use the same question title as [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/145290/can-i-marry-a-girl-if-im-also-a-girl) but revised it to be shorter and directed at Skyrim.

Comment: Why the change in the title?

Comment: @Braiam *shrugs* probably not wanting to have 2 identically title questions maybe, to be honest i can't remember the reasoning, just that i wasn't sure on adopting children and same sex marriage when i was planning out my family bloodline for after morrowind and that the same sex marriage question was similar to my Harvest Moon one

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The cap is two, regardless of which property you use.

As a side note, I think you might even be able to divide the children between properties. Like having one live in Proudspire, one live in Lakeview, etc.

By default you can adopt:

- Runa Fair-Shield
- Hroar
- Samuel
- Francois Beaufort

However, there is a list towards the bottom of [the Skyrim wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Adoption), where it outlines different children that will actually get sent to orphanages and become adoptable if you murder their parents, which is hilarious.

Comment: +1 for the last sentence. Actually made me laugh hard. :D

Comment: I don't play Skyrim, but killing people to adopt their children is a pretty impressive mechanic. I should give it a go sometime.

Answer (score 12):

By default, Hearthfire will only allow you to adopt up to two children. If you are playing on PC there [are mods](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/29249/?) to allow for more. However, in order to adopt you must have a house (either a homestead or one of the houses obtained by being thane of a given city), and the house must have a bed and a chest for each child. This means either buying the Children's bedroom package for a house, or building child's beds and chests in either the main hall or the optional bedroom wing (The dresser between the two beds counts as the chest for both children in the main hall).

There are four children available for adoption by default:

- Alesan - In Dawnstar
- Blaise - In Solitude
- Lucia - In Whiterun
- Sofie - In Windhelm

As well as an additional four* from the orphanage in Riften once Grelod the Kind *takes a permanent vacation*:

- Runa Fair-Shield
- Hroar
- Samuel
- Francois Beaufort
- *other children can be sent to the orphanage if their parent(s) should happen to die.

[The Elder Scrolls Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Adoption) has a full list of adoptable children, and other information related to adopting.

Comment: The mod you mention is also available for the XBox One:  https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/3393109