# What do I need to do in order to adopt sofie?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I own a house in whiterun, and solitude (w/ housecarls and children's bedrooms in both) I have already adopted Lucia and Blaine, but i want to adopt sofie so she's not sleeping in the cold and I have a bedroom ready for her, however it won't give me that option. I've looked thru wiki but it didn't necessarily answer my question. Is there a quest I need to complete first or do I have to get rid of Blaine or Lucia? [image]

Oh and whenever I go to windhelm I try to find Sofie and I buy everything she has then I put tons of food and stuff in her inventory and buy it, I repeat this until I give her about 100 coins, am I waisting my time doing this?

Answer (score 3):

In Skyrim (with Hearthstone DLC) you can only adopt a total of two children. Quoted [here by TheNeeoo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/172128/how-many-children-can-i-adopt):

> The cap is two, regardless of which property you use.

Also, for others, if you have trouble adopting children, make sure you follow the requirements shown [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Adoption):

> In a homestead, a child's bed can be fitted in the Bedrooms or a single bed fitted in the Main Hall. When in the Main Hall the dresser in between the two single beds counts as a chest for both possible children. Otherwise, if there are two child beds, there must be two child chests. If there are two beds but one chest, adoption will still not be allowed.

There may be other certain requirements not mentioned above that depend on homes and upgrades.

Comment: OP doesn't mention platform - there are mods to allow unlimited adoptions on PC.